# Where does the "superheated ground laser" originate?

Tags: history-of, anime, weapon

I've noticed a specific type of laser weapon appearing in various places. Instead of dealing damage by making contact with the target, most of the damage is inflicted by the laser's effects on the ground. It typically burns a white-hot path across the ground, which then detonates after a moment or two. If present in a video game, the laser itself may deal no damage at all, and the only harm is inflicted by the explosions coming in its wake.

I have several videos of the effect I'm describing, both timestamped to the moments when the weapon in question is fired. One is from the 1984 anime film Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind, found [here](https://youtu.be/aSYoPrT8TgA?t=104). The other is from the 2017 video game Guilty Gear Xrd Revelator, found [here](https://youtu.be/4D8DuxYUTYQ?t=48).

The fact that such a weapon was shown in a major film in 1984 means the trope goes back some time. However, I'm no expert in 70s science fiction, Japanese or otherwise. Was there any weapon with a similar function in previous media? Even if it wasn't the very first instance of such a weapon, I'm especially curious in finding out if there was a single piece of media behind it, either originating in Japan, or imported and popular enough to inspire so many creators.

Comment: When I saw Nausicaa, I thought it was just fuel exploding. I can't think of any obvious method for a delayed explosion caused by a laser.

Comment: It's not quite the same thing but Flash Gordon - The Deadly Ray From Mars 1938 has a heck of a laser hitting the ground.

Comment: The Star Wars program in the late 1980's US had orbital nukes that created x-ray lasers and melted cities from orbit without poisoning them with hot fallout.  The "dust would settle" later, but that would give it a few days to burn off its half-life in orbit instead of on the ground.  Might not have been fiction.

Comment: @EngrStudent Late 80s would be after the release of Nausicaa in 1984, so for that to be the inspiration we'd need a more exact date when that information was released.

Comment: Godzilla's breath weapon had similar effect much earlier.  Real Genius had a laser effect, but more about pranking the bad guy with Chekov's gun.